# Why are desktop folders suddenly showing file dates?

Tags: nautilus, files, icons, desktop-environments

Yesterday when I turned on my machine all the folders and documents on my desktop (two monitors) had dates below them. It makes for a very cluttered desktop!

Any ideas on how to lose the dates? I've attached a screenshot of one corner of a monitor.

[image: screenshot of desktop with dated folders]

Answer (score 18):

**1. The Issue:**

You have perhaps *inadvertently* made a change to the Nautilus settings relating to icons, their 'Zoom' level and/or the default information that is displayed underneath them.

Note that the amount of 'Zoom' applied to the icons will also affect the *total information* seen below the icon and there are 3 *available* information settings, each of which can be seen at *different* Zoom levels.

**2. The Solution:**

To rectify the issue you have seen follow this trail from within a Nautilus window:

```
Edit --> Preferences --> Display --> Icon Captions
```

The setting to look for is the 'Modified' tab at *the top* of the 3 selection boxes which I believe you will find *has been selected*. Below is a screenshot to demonstrate where I have repeated your setting and demonstrated the appropriate dialogue box to alter this setting:

[image]

Experiment a little with these settings (if the top box is found 'Modified' set to None') and all should then  be well. Note that for the Desktop a *refresh* will be required, perhaps the easiest way is to simply log out and then log back in...

**2b. Altering Zoom:**

If you simply wish to alter the 'Zoom' value of your Desktop icons (making these icons smaller will doubtless *also* conceal the Modification times) follow a similar trail from within a Nautilus window:

```
Edit --> Preferences --> Views --> Icon View Defaults
```

and alter the Zoom level until you are happy. A screenshot from my own system:

[image]

And then all should be well :)

Comment: Just a `CTRL +` will create  the same effect... ;-)  if somehow the desktop background get focus. Changing zoom level in `nautilus` adds information under the icons.

Comment: @Rmano I could use this technique in a Nautilus window but could not do it it on the Desktop?

Comment: I am not sure. I use Ubuntu Gnome  and there you can't practically focus it, so the commands go to another window...